# how to get customer ID from an URL?

Tags: html, python-3.x, url

i created a survey link that when my customer click the survey link in their inbox that i sent to him, he will automatically log into my survey page. But how can i grab their IDs from that URL that he logged in?
let's say the URL after he log in is like this: `xxxxx/id=%123456789`

So how to grab that ID 123456789 in my Python script?

Comment: Are you sure about that `%` character in the URL? It seems wrong.

Comment: As the ID is a parameter, you should pass it in the query string of the URL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)  survey?id=123456789. Also, you should not use your internal User ID to not expose this information. You should previously  assign a random GUID or Code to every account (and store it in a database) and use that in the link.